# SQL Query to select data

Tags: sql

I need some help with a SQL query

I have 3 tables - Person, Roles and Assignment

Person tables contains unique numbers which identify a person
Roles tables contains 2 columns, one which is the primary key identifies the role uniquely and the second is the role name. 
Assignment table contains 2 columns, the first is a foreign key to the person and the second is the foreign key to the Role, essentially showing us which person belong to which role

To simplify, let's think of the data as this:

**Person Table**

[image]

**Role Table**

[image]

**Assignment Table**

[image]

Now, I need to write a query which only returns people who do not belong to a role beginning with TEST_. A user can belong to any number of roles, but I need to find users who do not have any TEST_ roles assigned to them. So, using my example, it should only return P3

It looks simple, but I'm a bit stuck and I can't figure this out!

Any help will be much appreciated

If it helps, I'm using an Oracle 11g backend.

Comment: Did you try anything yourself? StackOverflow is not supposed to do your homework.

Comment: Hmmm.  it *does* seem a little textbook now that you mention it.  Should I delete my answer?

Comment: I assure you this is not homework :). I'm fairly new to SQL and I'm having an off day today. I've simplified my example a lot but the actual requirement is more complex but this is the key missing piece

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the tables then use a not like.

```
SELECT a.FK_PersonID 
FROM Assignment a 
JOIN Roles r
ON r.RoleID = a.FK_RoleID
WHERE r.RoleName NOT LIKE "TEST_%"
```

Comment: Oops I just noticed you said Oracle and my answer is in MySQL. I am unfamiliar with Oracle so I apologize if this does not work.

Comment: Really?  This query doesn't include P1, for example, in the result?

Comment: Yes it does, it returns 2 P1s(R2, R3), 1 P2(R2) and 2 P3s(R2, R3).

Answer (score 1):

Use `not exists`.  Like this:

```
SELECT p.personid
FROM person_table p
WHERE not exists ( SELECT 'any test role for person' 
                   FROM   assignment_table a INNER JOIN role_table r ON r.roleid = a.fk_roleid
                   WHERE  r.role_name like 'Test\_%' escape '\'
                   AND    a.fk_personid = p.person_id )
```